# Identify a Thyristor

Tags: scr

Hello would anybody be able to find the spec's of this SCR Thyristor General Electric C50FX425 937

[image: General Electric C50FX425 937]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude, that's a high power, high voltage thyristor. *You don't want to use that.* I can see absolutely no use case where this would be an appropriate component when you don't know the specs when it was bought. This thyristor was in use at least once – and you stand a solid chance of experiencing an explosive surprise if you used it in an application where this thyristor would make sense. If you're in the business of building rectifiers for > 10 kW power substations, this is a device of interest to your, or if you build supplies for electric trains. Else, scrap it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I can think of several (potentially lethal) hobbyist use cases for that SCR. For example, it'd be perfect for blowing up stuff with a capacitor bank or firing a crude coilgun.

Answer (score 2):

I am not as pessimistic as others regarding the viability of an old thyristor. If it is not shorted, there is a good possibility that it will work. These devices are either good or obviously failed.

It requires a substantial heatsink. A little terminal attached to the stud as shown in your picture is not sufficient for any significant use. The heatsink shown below was designed for blower cooling a similar device.

**Cross Reference:**

I found information to indicate the C50F is a 2N1910 rated 70 to 110 amps, peak repetitive off-state or reverse voltage: 50 volts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I agree with you.  It works or shorted.

Comment: I agree with Charles. There's been very little improvement in SCRs since this thing was made, and they don't generally die from sitting on the shelf. I can think of a few possible applications. It has a rugged hermetic package, which is an advantage. There might be some applications where we would today use a MOSFET rather than a low-voltage SCR but not all. Check out the GE SCR manual link Marcus posted for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer these questions:

So, you'll probably find your thyristor series (C50) on page 620 in the "GE SCR Manual":

https://archive.org/details/GESCRManual1964

That publication is from 1964.

This is 2017.

You don't want to use a thyristor with a design that's >53 years old.

This thyristor is meant for currents > 100 A. If you have an application for that, you **definitely** just want to buy a new one. These are currents that you simply don't want to handle with devices of unknown state. No excuses.

If you have applications that require far smaller currents, just go and spend a Euro or two on a new device with low forward voltage and a known datasheet that was stored under controlled conditions at an electronics distributor of your choice. No excuses.

Generally, even for such basic devices as the thyristor, there have been technological advances in the last 50 years, often just in quality and reliability aspects. There's very rarely good reason to use really vintage devices.

Comment: I have a collectors item.   Cool.  Thanks for the info.